# PHP: Get Value from String within Array

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
["entity_id"] => "1"
["customer_id"] => "18"
["public_hash"] => "xxxxxxxxxx041e6f5246f041429424422795137118223d73bb6197410f9cbc77"
["payment_method_code"] => "braintree"
["type"] => "card"
["created_at"] => "2018-12-19 21:24:13"
["expires_at" => "2020-06-01 00:00:00" "gateway_token"] => "8cx9y7"
["details"] => "{"type":"AE","maskedCC":"0005","expirationDate":"05\\\\\\\\/2020"}"
["is_active"] => "1"
["is_visible"] => "1"
```

And I'm trying to get the values from `["details"]` separately (type, maskedCC, expirationDate)

Using **$details = $card->getData('details');** I'm able to narrow it down to:

```
{"type":"AE","maskedCC":"0005","expirationDate":"05\/2020"}
```

From there, I'm not sure how to get the values AE, 0005, 05/2020.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a string and looks to be valid JSON, you can just decode it:

```
$details = json_decode($card->getData('details'), true);

if (!empty($details))
{
    //Valid JSON
    echo $details['type'];
    echo $details['maskedCC'];
    echo $details['expirationDate'];
}
else
{
    echo 'The details string was not valid JSON.';
}
```

Comment: ahh, not sure why I didn't realize that.. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You're dealing with a jsonObj.
You've to decode it to array first.
$key will be the attribute you want to get like (type, maskedCC, expirationDate)

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($details,true);
echo $jsonArray[$key];
```